# How to disable callout for user location annotation in Mapbox?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

How do I disable the "You are here" callout attached to the user location annotation in Mapbox in Swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement the following method which checks for the user location annotation.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
    if annotation is MGLUserLocation {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```